# PayPal Chained Payments Button?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

This is the current code I use for PayPal buttons:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="19.95">
<input type="image" src="pay-button.png" name="submit">
</form>
```

However, I need to integrate PayPal Adaptive Chained payments on my HTML website.  In the code above it's simple, I enter my email address, name of the product, and the amount it costs.

Is there any way to create a simple button like this for chained payments via PayPal?  I simply want the primary PayPal account sent 85% and the secondary account sent 15%.  Is there simple code that could be used to create a button like this?  Where simply the emails, percentages, and price can be entered?

I've tried search PayPal's developer area, but a lot of that seems way over my head for what I'm trying to do - creating a simple button :)  I know that I have to enter my app information somewhere in the code and it's a bit different from standard payments.  But I can't seem to find any simple code for this...

Any help that anyone can provide for this would be extremely helpful.  I've been searching for sample code all day and can't really find anything that does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chained Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) is a part of [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), which is a subset of [PayPal Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) (subscription required to process credit cards), which is entirely API based.

There is no comparable system in [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) (which is what you're using in your example)